# The smallest initial ordinal which is not defined using first-order formulas with parameters of smaller ordinals?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

Let $\theta_\alpha$ be the smallest ordinal such that there is no first-order formula $\phi$ such that:

$$\exists\beta_0,\beta_1...\beta_n\in\alpha\forall x(\phi(x,\theta_{\beta_0},\theta_{\beta_1}...\theta_{\beta_n})\Leftrightarrow x=\theta_\alpha)$$

Unless $\alpha=0$, in which case $\theta_0$ is the smallest ordinal with no first-order formula $\phi$ such that:

$$\forall x(\phi(x)\Leftrightarrow x=\theta_0)$$

With this definition, $\alpha\leq\theta_\alpha<|\alpha|^+$ (and thus $|\theta_\alpha|=|\alpha|$). These two arguments are shown separately from one another. ($\alpha\leq\theta_\alpha$ is because $\theta_\alpha$ is greater than or equal to a certain normal function at every point, and $\theta_\alpha<|\alpha|$ because for the set of all first-order formulas $\phi(v)$, which has cardinality $\aleph_0$, it can be shown that $\theta_\alpha$ has an injection onto $\aleph_0\cdot{}^{<\omega}|\alpha|$.)

However, because $\theta$ itself is not a normal function, it is currently unknown whether or not $\theta$ has any fixed points at all. If $\theta_\kappa=\kappa$ for an initial ordinal $\kappa$, then $\kappa$ is an $\aleph$-fixed point, a fixed point of the enumeration of those, etc.

It is also known (using a simple argument from Klev's $\mathcal{O}^{++}$) that $\theta_0>\zeta$ where $\zeta$ is the supremum of all eventually writable ordinals. This should give one an idea of how large these ordinals are. In fact, $\theta_0$ is the supremum of all first-order defined ordinal notation supremums. This information is not very pertinent to the question at hand, however.

Let $\Theta_0$ be the smallest $\kappa$ such that $\theta_\kappa=\kappa$. If $\Theta_0$ is inaccessible, it is the $\Theta_0$-th inaccessible. If $\Theta_0$ is Mahlo, it is the $\Theta_0$-th Mahlo. If $\Theta_0$ is Measurable, it is the $\Theta_0$-th Measurable. In general, if $\phi(\Theta_0)$ holds for a first-order formula $\phi$, then $\Theta_0$ is the $\Theta_0$-th ordinal such that $\phi(\kappa)$ holds.

**My question is this: Are there any initial ordinals $\kappa$ such that $\theta_\kappa=\kappa$? If so, what is the minimum of them? What axiomatic requirements are necessary for such a cardinal (if any other than ZF)?**

A bonus question which is completely unnecessary and possibly more difficult is generalizing this to $n$-th order logic, $\Sigma_n$, $\Pi_n$, or $\Delta_n$ formulas.

Comment: Do you restrict the complexity of $\phi$ in some way? Otherwise, it is possible that all ordinals are definable without parameters.

Comment: Following up on Yair's comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4597

Comment: @Yair I restrict $\phi$ to be finite and first-order. I also restrict you to only look at "Tall" models (models which contain every ordinal in $V$)

Comment: I feel like this is quite like your previous question https://mathoverflow.net/q/281377/1058. As was explained there, by Yair, it is not clear without further assumptions that even $\theta_0$ exists, so could you spell out exactly what you have in mind? Do you want your models to have access to a truth predicate, for example?

Comment: I would simply like to see if any models of ZFC have $\theta_0$ and if so what axioms are required to restrict ZFC to said models.

Comment: It would also be sufficient to simply say "In ZFC + $\Theta_0$ exists, it is _____" where _____ is replaced with some large cardinal property. In fact, I would even be satisfied with $\Theta_0$'s cofinality.

Comment: A remark about the title of the question: In Dor Marciano's master thesis, he analyzed the consistency strength of having the first undefinable ordinal ($\theta_0$) an uncountable cardinal (which is roughly inaccessible) or inaccessible (which is roughly Mahlo) and so on. He has a general technique for controlling this ordinal, which you might find interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under reasonable assumptions (to avoid such things as pointwise-definable models), there is indeed a $\kappa$ with $\theta_\kappa=\kappa$ and $cf(\kappa)=\omega$.

To see this, let $M(\alpha)$ be the supremum of the ordinals definable with parameters $<\alpha$. *Note that $M(\alpha)$ is not necessarily defined in an arbitrary model of ZFC - e.g. in a pointwise definable model, $M(0)$ already doesn't exist.* Now we define a sequence of ordinals as follows:

- $\beta_0=0$.
- $\beta_{n+1}=\vert M(\theta_{\beta_n})\vert^+$.

Let $\kappa=\sup\beta_i$. Clearly $\kappa$ is an initial ordinal with cofinality $\omega$, and $\theta_\kappa=\kappa$ follows immediately from the fact that $\kappa>M(\beta)$ for all $\beta<\kappa$. And in fact, by extending the $\beta$-sequence through $Ord$ in the obvious way, we get a club of $\theta$-fixed points (since $\theta_{\beta_\lambda}=\beta_\lambda$ whenever $\lambda$ is a nonzero limit ordinal).

The point is that while the function $\theta(-)$ itself need not be continuous everywhere, its composition with a sufficiently fast-growing function will be - we "smooth out" $\theta(-)$ with $\vert M(-)\vert^+$. *And note that this trick will work if we replace first-order logic with an arbitrary logic, **so long as** the appropriate suprema for that logic always exist.*

---

It is not immediately clear to me whether the $\kappa=\beta_\omega$ above is (in appropriate models anyways) the *least* initial ordinal which is a $\theta$-fixed point.

Comment: So this does solve the second question in the comments, but the question of what axiomatic requirements are necessary to warrant the existence of $\Theta_0$ are there; for example, does the existence of a weakly inaccessible imply the existence of $\Theta_0$? I still accept this question and commend you for your answer however.

Comment: @Zetapology See Theorem 4 and Observation 5 of [this paper on pointwise definable models](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.4597.pdf). If $P$ is a large cardinal compatible with V=HOD (and this includes basically everything), then we can have pointwise definable models realizing $P$ - and in a pointwise definable model, even $\theta_0$ doesn't exist. So you won't get such a simple sufficient condition. (That paper is well worth a read by the way, especially given your interests.)

Comment: Wow... I guess this cardinal is simply a really strong, yet somehow small type of cardinal.

Comment: Does the existence of a critical point of some nontrivial elementary embedding from $j:\mathrm{HOD}\rightarrow\mathrm{HOD}$ imply the existence of at least $\theta_0$? I know every Reinhardt cardinal is a $\theta$-Fixed point.

Comment: In fact, if $M$ is a transitive inner model of ZFC such that for every first order $\phi$ and every $v$ a finite sequence of ordinals in $M$, $\phi(v)\Leftrightarrow M\models\phi(v)$ (i.e. $M$ is almost "complete" in a sense), then the critical point of an elementary embedding $j:V\rightarrow M$ is always a theta fixed point.

Comment: @Zetapology "Wow... I guess this cardinal is simply a really strong, yet somehow small type of cardinal." No, the point is that the hypothesis "we are not in a pointwise definable model" is really orthogonal to the usual large cardinal hierarchy. There's no reason yet to believe that the existence of (say) a $\theta$-fixed point cardinal with cofinality $\omega$ should have high consistency strength over ZFC; it's just not *outright implied* by any of the standard large cardinal axioms (namely, those compatible with V=HOD).

Comment: Unless I am missing something, if $M$ is a well-founded model of ZFC whose ordinal height has uncountable cofinality, then there does exist a (least) fixpoint of $\theta$ in $M$. Thus, the “consistency strength” of the existence of such a model is fairly low (below an inaccessible cardinal).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yes, that's of course true. Not my finest moment. :P

Comment: Well, @EmilJeřábek, like Noah said, just because the existence of $\theta_0$ doesn't imply an inaccessible cardinal, doesn't mean it has low consistency strength. In fact, $V=HOD$ should not be compatible with an Inaccessible if it was below it, as he stated.

Comment: @Zetapology That's not what Emil said. Emil said that the **consistency strength** of the existence of $\theta_0$ (and more) is strictly below that of an inaccessible cardinal, which is true. He didn't claim that an inaccessible cardinal **proves** the existence of $\theta_0$.

Comment: @Zetapology Let me sketch why Emil's claim is true. Suppose $M$ is a model of ZFC with an inaccessible $\kappa$; I claim that in $M$, there is a set model of ZFC which is not pointwise definable (and - by the same argument - whose $\theta_0$ exists, and which has $\theta$-fixed points, and etc.). Specifically, think about $N:=V_\kappa^M$. $M$ proves that $N$ is uncountable, and can also define definability for set-sized structures, so $M$ can run the "math tea argument" to show that $N$ has an undefinable subset - that is, there is some $x\subset N$, $x\in M$ which is undefinable in $(N,\in$).

Comment: Now this might seem a problem if $M$ itself is pointwise definable, but it's not: just because $x$ is undefinable in $(N, \in)$ doesn't mean it's undefinable in $(M,\in)$! A definition of $x$ in $M$ may well exist "higher" than $N$ - e.g. $x$ may be coded into the continuum pattern in $M$ above $\kappa$.

Comment: Ah, ok. I see now.